# Storing R function in a class object in C++ using Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm trying to store a R function in a class object in C++ using Rcpp. However, I always get the error "no matching function for call to 'Rcpp::Function_ImplRcpp::PreserveStorage::Function_Impl()”. Can a function be stored in a class? The following is some sample code.

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

//------------------------------------ Class Specific Functions -------------------------------------------//
class A{
  
public:
  
  Rcpp::Function f;
  
  
  // public member functions;
  A(Rcpp::Function & f);
    
};

A::A(Rcpp::Function & f0)
{
  f = f0;
}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site. You need to provide a [mre] so that other users can replicate your error and provide necessary corrections. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, and thanks for your interest in Rcpp.  I am not sure how to say this politely (which is why it took me a moment to comment here) but you are ... most likely thinking about this under the wrong framework. An R function only exists in the context of the R interpreter typically running "on top of" an R session in which we use Rcpp to talk from R to C++ and back.  You can't isolate it out.  So step back, so some reading of the existing documentation, study some existing packages and maybe rethink your approach.